# How to create a for loop to add elements in dictionaries in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, dictionary, collections

I am learning python and I am currently on dictionaries and chainmaps. Below is my code-

```
import collections

def dict1():
global dt1
dt1 = {}
r1 = int(input("Enter size of dictionary:"))
for i in range(r1):
    c = input("Enter key name:")
    b = input("Enter key value:")
    dt1[c] = b
print(dt1)

def dict2():
global dt2
dt2 = {}
r2 = int(input("Enter size of dictionary:"))
for j in range(r2):
    z = input("Enter key name:")
    y = input("Enter value:")
    dt2[z] = y
print(dt2)


def main():
dict1()
dict2()
chain = collections.ChainMap(dt1, dt2)
print(chain.maps, '\n')

if __name__=="__main__":
main()
```

I wanted to ask if there is a way to create a "for" loop for creating dictionaries as many dictionaries as per the user requirements and then adding them all to a ChainMap either one by one or all at a time.

Comment: Instead of multiple global variables "dt1", "dt2",... you can store a list in one global variable and append new dicts to it.

Comment: Instead of multiple functions and global variables, all you needed was one function that created a dictionary based upon user inputs.  Then call that function twice to create dt1 and dt2 in main  i.e. `dt1 = create_dict(); dt2 = create_dict()`.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, it is not a good deed to create global variables if not necessary (ex. constants). Then, with a little help of documentation, there is a function called new_child() which adds new dictionary to a chainmap.

With that knowledge, you should be able to do a normal for loop. Before the loop, you define the chainmap and then add as many dictionaries as are needed.

Something like:

```py
# how many dictionaries
count = int(input("Number of dictionaries"))

# init empty chainmap
my_chainmap = collections.ChainMap()

# loop 'count' times
for i in range(count):
    new_dict = {}
    r = int(input("Enter size of dictionary:"))
    for i in range(r):
        c = input("Enter key name:")
        v = input("Enter key value:")
        new_dict[c] = b
    my_chainmap.new_child(new_dict)
    print(new_dict)
```

Comment: Is it possible that instead of declaring number of dictionaries, I can ask if the user wants to create a new one and every time user selects yes or Y, then create the dictionary to add it to the chainmap?

Comment: How can I change the name of the dictionaries created after the while loop so that all have unique name?

Comment: You don't actually need to make the names different.

if you add different dictionaries in a chainmap, your chainmap has no information of their names. It only stores the values of the dictionaries, not the variables.

You can read more about this here: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/chainmap-in-python/

Comment: I am getting ChainMap({'name': 'mnbo', 'roll': '12'}, {'name': 'abcd'}, {}) as output
How to remove the last empty {}?

Comment: I am not really sure how your code looks like at this stage. You should definitely look why that last dictionary is added in your code? Try to find where does it come from? What does the last loop of for / while loop do? Good luck

Comment: No problem. If you find anything I wrote helpful, little upvote or helpful flag would be great :)